# No able to sign the transaction

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio-code, keosd

I have followed the documentation and followed the mentioned steps, However I am not able to sign the transaction, I guess that's because I don't know on which port Keosd is running, also kindly send me the POST body of sign transaction which i can test in postman.

Kindly help

Comment: Which documentation? Can you post a link? What do you mean to be unable to sign a transaction? Does cleos returns an error?

Comment: I followed this for the basic steps:
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets and https://steemit.com/eos/@noprom/using-eos-rpc-api-to-transfer-eos
Here in the above link, They have shown how to sign a transaction, But i am getting error not found, 404. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have followed EOSBlock/EOS-Tutorials documentation. If so then you have to add the chain ID into the payload of sign_transaction.

```
[
  {
    "ref_block_num": 246190,
    "ref_block_prefix": 1753012779,
    "expiration": "2018-05-24T15:30:32.000",
    "actions": [
      {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "eosio",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": "0000000000ea305500000000487a2b9d102700000000000004454f53000000001163726561746564206279206e6f70726f6d"
      }
    ],
    "signatures": []
  },
  [
    "EOS6gXwNz2SKUNAZcyjzVvg6KdNgA1bSuVzCr8c5yWkGij52JKx8V"
  ],
  ""
]
```

This is probably the data you have passed. There is a blank filed "" just below the signatures field. Add chain ID into that field and try again.

If it is not working or it was not the problem, share your error log. So that we can discuss deeply

Comment: I di what you said, But in postman I am getting the below error
{
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "name": "exception",
        "what": "unspecified",
        "details": []
    }
}

May be the issue is with keosd running, I don't know

Comment: I am not using transfer action, I am just using the hi action of the hello contract

Comment: [
  {
    "ref_block_num": 923,
    "ref_block_prefix": 3193036849,
    "expiration": "2018-05-24T15:30:32.000",
    "actions": [
      {
        "account": "default",
        "name": "hi",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "eosio",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": "0000000000ea3055"
      }
    ],
    "signatures": []
  },
  [
    "myKey"
  ],
  "myChainId"
]

Comment: Make sure keosd is running and nodeos and keosd are running in different ports "cleos -u http://nodeosd:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8080 wallet create"

Comment: To change default keosd port, set http-server-address value in wallet config (~/eosio-wallet/config.ini)

Comment: I have the below line in my config.ini

# The local IP and port to listen for incoming http connections; leave blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
 http-server-address = 5441

Ques: Which port should i hit the sign transaction on ?
http://localhost:5441/v1/wallet/sign_transaction (This says could not get any response in postman)

Comment: Any port which you want to run keosd, say :8080

Comment: I am now getting blank response using http://localhost:8888/v1/wallet/sign_transaction

404 has gone

Comment: First of all run keosd in your system. 
goto eos/build/programs/keosd and run ./keosd

Comment: warn  2018-11-12T09:56:09.864 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:478           plugin_initialize    ] 13 St12out_of_range: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 5) > this->size() (which is 4)
rethrow basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 5) > this->size() (which is 4):
    {"what":"basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 5) > this->size() (which is 4)"}
    thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:478 plugin_initialize
Failed to initialize

Comment: run ./keosd got the above response

Comment: Just these two commands I used to start the Keosd and then the sign transaction worked 1) To kill the process
pkill keosd 2) keosd --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8900

Comment: 'sign_transaction' will work even if chain id is not given. But for performing 'push_transaction', you have to add chain id in "sign_transaction" payload as mentioned in this answer